# Adjacency List representation in C++, using class and pointers, head to lists not working properly

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am trying to implement adjacency lists using classes and pointers in C++. I have created a class of vertices, with an array of pointers pointing at each vertex. further in each vertex class, their is a linked list that should contain adjacency list of that vertex.

The following code runs, but does not give the correct adjacency list correctly. The head of the adjacency list changes, I don't know why. during passing pointers to different functions, this must be happening. The head gets assigned to the edge that is given to the function addToEdgeList() in some cases, but does not stay what is desired.

Here is my code. I can use C++ STL vectors to do this but this pointers issue is bugging me too much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class vertex;
int vertexCount = 0;
struct edge {
        int vertexIndex = 0;            //takes the index of vertex of which the edge is.
        edge *next = NULL;              //the adjacency list of that index.
};
class vertex    {
    std::string name;                   //name of the vertex. But it can only be called using numbers(0, 1, 2,...)
    struct edge *head;          //the beginning of the edge it points to.
    public:
        vertex()    {
            name = "";
            head = new edge;
            head = NULL;
        }
        vertex(std::string abc) {
            name = abc;
            head = NULL;
        //  vertexCount += 1;
        }
        edge * getEdgeBeg() {
            return head;
        }
        void setName(std::string abc)   {
            name = abc;
            vertexCount += 1;
        }
        void addToEdgeList(edge * e)    {
            if (head != NULL)   {
                edge *ptr = new edge;
                ptr = this->head;
                std::cout << name << "-" << ptr->vertexIndex << "-" << e->vertexIndex << std::endl;
                while(ptr->next != NULL)    {
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }
                ptr->next = e;

            }
            else    {
                head = e;
            }
            std::cout << head->vertexIndex << " " << name << " " << e->vertexIndex << std::endl;    
        }
        void printEdgeList()    {
            edge *ptr = new edge;
            ptr = head;
            while(ptr)  {
                std::cout << " ->" << ptr->vertexIndex;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            delete ptr; 
        }
        void printName()    {
            std::cout << name;
        }
        ~vertex()   {
            delete head;
        }
}*graph[15];


void addEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2)  {
    edge *temp1 = new edge;
    edge *temp2 = new edge;
    temp1->vertexIndex = vertex2;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    graph[vertex1]->addToEdgeList(temp1);
    temp2->vertexIndex = vertex1;
    temp2->next = NULL;
    graph[vertex2]->addToEdgeList(temp2);
    delete temp1;
    delete temp2;
}
void printGraph()   {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)    {
        graph[i]->printName();
        std::cout << " (" << i << ")";
        graph[i]->printEdgeList();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()  {
    vertex *vptr[15];

    vptr[0] = new vertex;
    vptr[0]->setName("A");
    graph[0] = vptr[0];

    vptr[1] = new vertex;
    vptr[1]->setName("B");
    graph[1] = vptr[1];

    vptr[2] = new vertex;
    vptr[2]->setName("C");
    graph[2] = vptr[2];

    addEdge(0, 1);
    addEdge(0, 2);
    addEdge(1, 2);
    printGraph();
}
```

Comment: What did you learn from the debugger?

Comment: Also please bear in mind that if you `new` a piece of memory, you should probably also `delete` it at some point (look at `addToEdgeList`, and then look at `~vertex()`)

Comment: Look at your `addEdge` function.  Does it look right to you, allocating memory, pointing to it by adding the pointer to the edge list, and then deallocating that very same memory?  If you can't see the obvious huge flaw in that, then it would be a good time to review a tutorial on dynamically allocated memory and pointers.

Comment: *I can use C++ STL vectors to do this but this pointers issue is bugging me too much* --  So create your own `vector` class and use it.  That is much better learning experience than doing one-off allocations of `new` and `delete` as you're doing now.  By making your own vector class, you learn allocation, deallocation, copy / assignment, etc.  Then you take that tool you built and use it in your adjacency list program.   You learn none of those things writing code like you've written.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @PaulMcKenzie.. removed those de-allocations and got my code running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors on deallocating your pointers.
First, don't do `edge *ptr = new edge;` but `edge *ptr = head;` and after, remove your `delete` on `*ptr`.
In `addEdge` function, you add your edges pointers to your graph, so, as they are pointers, you should not `delete` them at the end of the function, otherwise your graph will point on NULL.
This is my output:

```
1 A 1
0 B 0
A-1-2
1 A 2
0 C 0
B-0-2
0 B 2
C-0-1
0 C 1
A (0) ->1 ->2
B (1) ->0 ->2
C (2) ->0 ->1
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it working. Also the above code works if I don't take graph array as pointers.

Comment: Take care also on your memory loss, there are several. Try to use valgrind if you don't use it yet.